# Passing null to child() in Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The method `.child()`, documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#child), in the Firebase Database security rules may be passed a value from else where in the database as such.

```
{
  ".read": "newData.child('someField')
                   .child(root.child('someFieldInDb').val()).val() === 'someValue'"
}
```

What happens when `someFieldInDb` has no value and returns null. Essentially what happens when you pass null to `.child()`? I imagine some exception is thrown, does that mean the rule fails? If so, is this acceptable logic?